# Angular Upgrade from Version 7 to Version 12

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-upgrade

i have upgraded to version 12 and when i try to compile (ngserve),i am getting the below error

```
Compiling @angular/http : es2015 as esm2015
D:\EclipseWS1.3\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\writing\in_place_file_writer.js:58
                    throw new Error("Tried to overwrite " + backPath + " with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.");
                    ^

Error: Tried to overwrite D:/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/browser_xhr.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.
```

I have tried deleting the node module folder and did fresh npm install

but nothing helps.please help me in resolving

Comment: Try with removing `node_modules` + `package-lock.json` Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130728/tried-to-overwrite-angular-cdk-stepper-step-header-d-ts-ivy-ngcc-bak-with-an

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I have already tried the above options,but doesnt help.

Comment: did you also remove the package-lock file ?